# C++ opencv How to expand Mat dims

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow

My `tensorflow` model expects images to have shape: `[1, 1080, 1920, 3]` and i'm trying to reshape frame that i captured from video.

It seems easy to do it using python and numpy: `np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)`
But I have no idea how to do it on c++ using `Mat` from `opencv`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do the OpenCV docs say for cv::Mat ?

Answer (score 0):

yeah, there is a simple function called resize :)

> C++: void resize(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, Size dsize, double fx=0, double fy=0, >int interpolation=INTER_LINEAR );

your question is basically answered here [Resize an image type "Mat" opencv C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625621/resize-an-image-type-mat-opencv-c) , but IIRC (in contrast to what he stated there), dst can be pre-created or just a reference and it will create it automatically.

see documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#void%20resize(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation)) under 'resize' function for more detailed explanation on how to use it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it isn't a duplicate of that other thing either.  They are looking to keep the same number of elements, but add a singleton dimension.  That is: newmat = mat; mat.size = newmat.size = [1, mat.size[0],... mat.size[n]]; newmat.step = ?